# Need help understanding different outputs of strtonum

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, octal

So I'm trying to get into CTFs and the first one I'm doing is the picoCTF 2019. I used `gawk` and `strtonum()` to solve one of the problems. Basically, I had to look at this output:

```
  49734 231 160
  49735 235 151
  49736 230 143
  49737 310 157
  87663  12 103
 162650 364 124
 175231 153 106
 175232 261 173
 211986 230 164
 211987 222 150
 211988  15  63
 211989 330 171
 284427 122 162
 292340 174  63
 292341 371 137
 331830 216 141
 331831 365  65
 426632 346 137
 439903 360 144
 515770 112  61
 515771 252 146
 583608 341 146
 640996 310  63
 688795  77 162
 688796 107  63
 702943  23 156
 751424 243 164
 754731  61 137
 754732 113  64
 754733 274 163
 754734 304 137
 796226  43 142
 871159 256 165
 871160   6  67
 871161 316  67
 871162 346  63
 927506 347 162
 927507 212 137
 927508 122  64
 994666 376 156
 994667  43 144
 994668 377 137
1068577 234 152
1068578 344  63
1068579 203  61
1068580 222  61
1068581 162 171
1101444   5 137
1101445 173 141
1101446   7 163
1101447 300 154
1171017  53 153
1171018 147 152
1171019 356 146
1241182  51 144
1241183 224 163
1241184 200 141
1241185 106 154
1272572 217 153
1272573 156 146
1337150   4 163
1410459 345 154
1410460 340 153
1460208   5 146
1510914 237 154
1567157 322 153
1567158 100 152
1567159  42 144
1567160 220 163
1567161 205 146
1581925 315 144
1581926 244 163
1581927 215 172
1581928 147 155
1581929 257 172
1677065 176  61
1677066 341  60
1764510 357  65
1764511 210  64
1764512  31  70
1766742  13 175
```

which is from the command `cmp -l kitters.jpg cattos.jpg`, and decode the octal ASCII encodings of the strings in the third column.

To accomplish the task, I used this command:

```
cmp -l kitters.jpg cattos.jpg | gawk '{printf "%c", strtonum(0$3)}' && echo
```

which gave the desired output, the flag:

```
picoCTF{th3yr3_a5_d1ff3r3nt_4s_bu773r_4nd_j311y_aslkjfdsalkfslkflkjdsfdszmz10548}
```

However, before finding this solution, I tried this command:

```
cmp -l kitters.jpg cattos.jpg | gawk '{printf "%c", strtonum($3)}' && echo
```

which is exactly the same as the other command except that there is no `0` before `$3`. It gave this ouput:

```
g|j­¤?«¢?A=?¢?¤@£¥CC?¢@?==«£££££¬=<A@F¯
```

I'm just curious why these two commands gave very different outputs, and what the significance of the `0` in `strtonum()` is. I assume it is related to octal, but I couldn't find confirmation on that anywhere.

Comment: too much data ;-) (but I didn't down vote). Please read [mcve] before posting more Qs. Glad you got a solution below. Don't forget to accept the answer that helps/answers your Q. Good luck.

Comment: Just because you `had to look at this output` doesn't mean we have to! Come up with a **minimal** example that demonstrates your problem and you'll get far more people with the time to invest reading it to try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual describes `strtonum` like this:

> `strtonum(str)`
>
> Examine `str`, and return its numeric value.  **If `str` begins with a leading `0`,  treat  it
>                                  as  an octal number**.  If `str` begins with a leading `0x` or `0X`, treat it as a hexadecimal
>                                  number.  **Otherwise, assume it is a decimal number**.

So, as you can see below, `160` and `0160` are different numbers; it's all documented.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { print strtonum("160"), strtonum("0160") }'
160 112
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've taken a closer look at the `gawk` man page. Thanks so much for the help!